# Get Checkbox total count & save value in textbox if checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have written below code to get a total count of Checked chechbox and save the value checked value comma separated in textbox.

**HTML:**

```
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='1' onchange='checkCount(this.value);'></label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='2' onchange='checkCount(this.value);'></label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='3' onchange='checkCount(this.value);'></label>

<input type="text" name="proId" id="proId">
```

**JS:**

```
function checkCount(elm) {
  var cheCount = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
  document.getElementById('selectCount').innerHTML = cheCount;

  definVal = document.getElementById('proId').value ;
  var inval = elm+","+definVal;
  document.getElementById('proId').value = inval;

  if(cheCount==0){
    document.getElementById('proId').value = "";
  }
}
```

Check the output in below image:
[image]

My issue is that, when i unchecked the checkbox, its value is adding in textbox instead of getting remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make below changes, just call js method dont send its value

And then check by their classname

```js
function checkCount(elm) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox-btn");
      var selected = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
            selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
        }
      document.getElementById("proId").value = selected.join();
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = selected.length;
    }
```

```html
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='1' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
    <label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='2' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
    <label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='3' onchange='checkCount();'></label>

    <input type="text" name="proId" id="proId">

<div>Total Selected : <span id="total">0</span></div>
```